# How to print out a polynomial using values in an array using a for loop and To.String

Tags: c#

I'm trying to print out a polynomial expression of n size, where n is how many values are in the array. I'm using only one variable (x), the constant term at the end of the polynomial is always array[0] and coefficients are the elements after array[0], the powers are in descending order starting at array.length - 1. I've been trying to use a for loop to iterate through the array and assign the terms to the incrementing elements of the array, however, I don't know how to fully do this using a for loop to assign the terms and then print out using to.string method.

Any help would be appreciated!

This is what I have so far:

```
class MyPolynomial
    {
        private double[] _coeffs;
        private int degree;



        public MyPolynomial(double[] coeffs)
        {
            this._coeffs = coeffs;
            this.degree = coeffs.Length - 1;
        }
        public int GetDegree()
        {
            return this.degree;
        }

        public override String ToString()
        {
            string term = null;
            string variable = "x";
            string constant = _coeffs[0].ToString();



            for (int i = 1; i < _coeffs.Length; i++)
            {
                if (_coeffs[i] == 0)
                {
                    term = null;
                }
                else
                {
                    term = _coeffs[i].ToString() + variable + "^" + degree;
                }
            }

class TestMyPolynomial
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            MyPolynomial tomPolynomial = new MyPolynomial(new double[] { 28, 6, 8});


            tomPolynomial.ToString();
}
}
```

Comment: If I was only able to use a for loop, how would I go about doing so?

Comment: You can do similar to `.Select()`. Iterate over each coefficient and use [`StringBuider`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.stringbuilder?view=netcore-3.1) to append each part of expression. I believe you can do it. Let me know if you need any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `.Select()` to create polynomial term

```
var result = string.Join("+ ", _coeffs.Select((x, i) => $"{x}^{_coeffs.Length - i - 1}"));
```

your entire `.ToString()` function will look like

```
public override String ToString()
{
     return string.Join("+ ", _coeffs.Select((x, i) => $"{x}^{_coeffs.Length - i - 1}"));
}
```

[.Net Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/GRQU2c)

- Iterate each coefficient using [`Select()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select?view=netcore-3.1#System_Linq_Enumerable_Select__2_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Func___0_System_Int32___1__).
- Create expression using [string interpolation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated) to create your expression and store it.
- Now join string using operator. I used `+` as an operator.

Comment: Thanks for your help!